# How can I ignore a string in python regex group matching?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following string

```
>>> mystr = 'A-ABd54-Bf657'
```

(a random string of dash-delimited character groups) and want to match the opening part, and the rest of the string, in separate groups. I can use

```py
>>> re.match('(?P<a>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)-(?P<b>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', mystr)
```

This produces a `groupdict()` like this:

```py
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'ABd54-Bf657'}
```

How can I get the same regex to match group `b` but separately match a specific suffix (or set of suffices) if it exists (they exist)? Ideally something like this

```py
>>> myregex = <help me here>
>>> re.match(myregex, 'A-ABd54-Bf657').groupdict()
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'ABd54-Bf657', 'test': None}    
>>> re.match(myregex, 'A-ABd54-Bf657-blah').groupdict()
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'ABd54-Bf657-blah', 'test': None}
>>> re.match(myregex, 'A-ABd54-Bf657-test').groupdict()
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'ABd54-Bf657', 'test': 'test'}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mystr = 'A-ABd54-Bf657'
re.match('(?P<a>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)-(?P<b>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+?)(?:-(?P<test>test))?$', mystr)
                                                 ^                    ^
```

The first indicated `?` makes the `+` quantifier non-greedy, so that it consumes the minimum possible.

The second indicated `?` makes the group optional.

The `$` is necessary or else the non-greediness plus optionality will match nothing.

Comment: was missing that first extra `?` to make a non-greedy `+`, excellent, thanks.

Comment: I am deleting my answer but original answer didn't have `$` in the end and `+?` as in my answer.